# Disk Management Action History/log

Tags: windows, partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I deleted a partition in disk management earlier today, and then extended the partition before it over the newly unallocated space, and now need to recover a file from it.  Does Disk Management keep any log files or anything around that might tell me what sector the deleted partition stopped at, or anything?  Is there another way to get the partition table from then?  (I'm trying to use Active Partition Recovery to find the old partition, but it doesn't seem to be finding it using my mental estimation of where the new partition should start, and I don't have time to scan the entire disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Windows does not log partition details for activities performed in the Disk Management MMC snap-in or by the `DISKPART` command. To my recollection there are events logged in the System Event Log when a volume is created and deleted (with the **ntfs** and **userpnp** sources) but these events make no mention of the sectors involved.

Lacking the necessary layout details of your disk it sounds like you'll have to use the automatic scan feature of your partition recovery tool.